# Why left-shifting operation with different result on __u32 and __u64?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I tried left-shifting a unsigned int by 24 like below,

```
    __u8 buf;
    __u32 u32_result = 0;
    __u64 u64_result = 0;
    buf=0xFF;        
    u32_result= (buf<<24);                          
    u64_result= (buf<<24);                   

    printf("sizeof(__u64):%lu, sizeof(__u32):%lu, sizeof(__u8):%lu,\n", sizeof(__u64), sizeof(__u32), sizeof(__u8));                           
    printf("u32_result: %u MB\n", u32_result);
    printf("u64_result: %llu MB\n", u64_result);
```

The execute result as below,

```
sizeof(__u64):8, sizeof(__u32):4, sizeof(__u8):1,
u32_result: 4278190080 MB
u64_result: 18446744073692774400 MB
```

And, I'm confusing about why the __u32 and __u64 have different result?
Is anyone can help me to figure-out? Thank a lot!

Comment: To catch this type of error, you can enable `-Wconversion` in your build flags: this will warn you about signed values being converted to unsigned.

Comment: Use hex formatting to investigate such effects, your u32 result is 0xFF000000 and u64 is 0xFFFFFFFFFF000000.

Answer (score 2):

`buf<<24` is promoted to an `int`, as is usual for operations on small types (besides, 24 is an `int`). Specifically, this is a `signed int`, not `unsigned`.

Since unsigned arithmetic wraps around, the point where it wraps around matters, and that's of course much higher for your `__u64`.

Comment: [This answer goes in depth about promotions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296/10805404).

Answer (score 0):

buf is converted to int then left shifted which gives a negative 32 bit integer. Assigned to 64 but it is first converted to a huge negative integer which becomes a huge 64 bit integer.

Safest is ((uint64_t) buf) << 24. BTW uint64_t is a standard C and C++ type, so the reader knows what’s going on unlike with your non-standard types.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably working on a system with 32bit `int`. What happens here is, that in the expression `buf << 24` both operands undergo integer promotion first and then the type of the result is inferred (You can read up the exact rules for the shift operator [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Shift_operators) and for the promotions [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions)). Because `buf` is of type `__u8` which is smaller than `int` it is promoted to `int` (the signed version). Shifting that right 24 bits is *undefined behavior*, because the result is not representable in the promoted type of lhs:

> For signed lhs with nonnegative values, the value of `LHS << RHS` is `LHS * 2 ^ RHS`
> if it is representable in the promoted type of lhs, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Shift_operators))

Tldr: Your left hand side operand must have a type that is wide enough to store the result of the shift. You can achieve this e.g. by casting it to `__u32`:

```
(__u32)buf << 24
```